# Access Data From UITextField in Separate Class

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I realize that it is not correct to call an IBOutlet from another class. How then would I access data from a UITextField to be read in a separate class, e.g.

```
class myClass {

var token = String()
@IBOutlet weak var textField = UITextField!

// Present what is typed in UITextField
textField.text! = token

// Print token
   print("Token: \(token)") 
}
```

The trouble I am having is here:

```
class myOtherClass {
var token = "\(textField)" // I know this is wrong

// Print same token from myClass
print("Token: \(token)" 

}
```

I realize that there is no reference or connection for this to make sense. I tried abstracting token into a class, struct and protocol in a .swift file and am completely lost. How could something like this work? myOtherClass does not have a UILabel: it is simply another object I'm updating. Help.

Comment: try add this with your textfield in myclass: UITextField().addTarget(otherClassInstance, action: otherClassFunc , forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

Comment: Not working on UITextField as an IBOutlet.